# Xamarin Button only registers click on corner

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-5

I have a Xamarin Forms project and I have a Content Page with a ListView in which I have two buttons to add or remove items from a Cart.

When I click on the remove button it works just fine but when I click on the add button it only works if I click it on the left corner. If I click somewhere else on the button it will register as if I click the entire item on the listView.

Also, I don't know why but the buttons change its size when clicked.

Here is how it is performing

[image]

And here is the code. The button that is not working properly is called `btnAdd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppCrijoya.Views.CartPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>

 
        
        <StackLayout Padding="0">

           
            
            <Grid RowSpacing="0" Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

               
                
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Padding="0,8" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0">Monto Total:</Label>
                        <Label x:Name="lblTotalCart" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black"  FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                        <Button VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnContinue" Text="Continuar" 
                                                    BackgroundColor="#353A47" FontSize="12" HeightRequest="35"
                                                    TextColor="White" Clicked="BtnContinue_Clicked" Padding="0" />
                    </Grid>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stkEmpty" IsVisible="False" Margin="0,220,0,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="bag.png" HeightRequest="40"></Image>
                        <Label  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">TU CESTA DE LA COMPRA ESTÁ VACÍA</Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
                    
                    <ListView  x:Name="CartListView" ItemsSource="{Binding oList}" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Frame Margin="3.5" CornerRadius="30">
                                        <Grid x:Name="Item" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" RowSpacing="6">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="155"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>
                                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition  Height="35"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <!--<StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                                        <Label Text="Cantidad" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>-->

                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                        <Label Text="Precio Unidad"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                        <Label Text="Precio Total"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                            <Button x:Name="btnRemove" 
                                                                    Grid.Column="0" 
                                                                    CornerRadius="15"
                                                                    BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"  
                                                                    WidthRequest="50" 
                                                                    HeightRequest="35" 
                                                                    Padding="0" Text="-"
                                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                                    Clicked="BtnRemove_Clicked"
                                                                    BorderWidth="0.3"
                                                                    TextColor="#353A47"
                                                                    BorderColor="#353A47"/>

                                                            <Button x:Name="btnAdd" 
                                                                    Grid.Column="2" 
                                                                    CornerRadius="15"
                                                                    BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"  
                                                                    WidthRequest="50" 
                                                                    HeightRequest="35" 
                                                                    Padding="0" Text="+"
                                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                                    Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"
                                                                    BorderWidth="0.3"
                                                                    TextColor="#353A47"
                                                                    BorderColor="#353A47"/>

                                                            <Label x:Name="lblQuantity" 
                                                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                                       Text="{Binding Quantity}" 
                                                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                                       FontSize="15"
                                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                                       HeightRequest="20"
                                                                       WidthRequest="30"/>
                                                           
                                                           

                                                        </Grid>
                                                        
                                                    </StackLayout>

                                                    <!-- <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="Retirar de bolsa" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" 
                                                    BackgroundColor="#9C2424" FontSize="10" HeightRequest="35"
                                                    TextColor="White" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" Padding="0" />-->

                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ScrollView>

            </Grid>
            
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Please help because I have no idea of why this is happening. Thanks.

**EDIT**

If I remove the label in between the two buttons it will work, don't know why

Comment: Maybe the Label is overlapping the Button a bit , you can put a Backgroudcolor to the Label and see were it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get more reliable behavior if you:

1. Add the missing RowDefinition, so Grid.Row="3" has height 35.

````xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <!-- ADD BELOW LINE -->
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>```
````

2. Remove the unneeded StackLayout. Change:

```xml
 <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

to:

```xml
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    ...
</Grid>
```

---

**IF** the above are not sufficient, you might need to add a `HeightRequest` or hardcoded `RowDefinition Height` somewhere. I realize this is not ideal - `Auto` heights are preferable, because they adapt as needed - but sometimes Xamarin Forms needs that extra hint.

The first place to try is to give the whole ItemTemplate a HeightRequest:

```xml
<ViewCell>
    <Frame ... HeightRequest="300" ...
```

If that works, then you might try instead putting that on one of the nested elements, to allow most of the content to be automatically sized.

---

**ALTERNATIVE** (If the first two items aren't enough)

Its possible to collapse any complex `ItemTemplate` layout to a SINGLE `Grid`. Then use StackLayout within cells as needed (but NO NESTED `Grid`s). This is done by use of `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` to describe areas of the overall grid. You can see this visually if you DIAGRAM the entire layout on a piece of paper, drawing vertical and horizontal lines around each section. Extend those lines all the way to edges of the outer grid.

Xamarin Forms should do a better job of figuring out the layout of this single Grid.

The page might also appear faster.

Comment: I finally solved it by adding a Grid.RowDefinition on my Grid.Column=1 under the Image. Removing the StackLayout as you said and moving the Grid.Row=3 out the Grid.Row=1. I don't know If I explained myself. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it , but beware if the number between is 1000 of lets say 4 characters or more .

Comment: @robluc, glad to hear. Be sure to upvote or accept any answer that is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the Label , like this .

```
<Button
x:Name="btnRemove"
Grid.Column="0"
Padding="0"
BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"
BorderColor="#353A47"
BorderWidth="0.3"                                                      
Clicked="BtnRemove_Clicked"
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
CornerRadius="15"
HeightRequest="35"
Text="-"
TextColor="#353A47"
WidthRequest="50" />

<Label
x:Name="lblQuantity"
Grid.Column="1"
FontAttributes="Bold"
FontSize="15"
HeightRequest="20"                                                           
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
Text="{Binding Quantity}"
VerticalOptions="Center"                                                           
VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
WidthRequest="30" />

<Button
x:Name="btnAdd"
Grid.Column="2"
Padding="0"
BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"
BorderColor="#353A47"
BorderWidth="0.3"
Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
CornerRadius="15"
HeightRequest="35"
Text="+"
TextColor="#353A47"
WidthRequest="50" />
```

Comment: It doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

I did a test based on your code,I found that the middle Label `lblQuantity`(`Label x:Name="lblQuantity")`  has covered button (`Button x:Name="btnAdd"` ), so you can just remove property `WidthRequest="30"` of the middle label (`lblQuantity`), just as follows:

```
                                      <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Button x:Name="btnRemove" 
                                                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                                                CornerRadius="15"
                                                                BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"  
                                                                WidthRequest="50" 
                                                                HeightRequest="35" 
                                                                Padding="0" 
                                                                Text="-"
                                                                Clicked="btnRemove_Clicked"
                                                                BorderWidth="0.3"
                                                                TextColor="#353A47"
                                                                BorderColor="#353A47"/>

                                            <Button x:Name="btnAdd" 
                                                                Grid.Column="2" 
                                                                CornerRadius="15"
                                                                BackgroundColor="#E5D3C2"  
                                                                WidthRequest="50" 
                                                                HeightRequest="35" 
                                                                Padding="0" 
                                                                Text="+"
                                                                Clicked="btnAdd_Clicked"
                                                                BorderWidth="0.3"
                                                                TextColor="#353A47"
                                                                BorderColor="#353A47"/>

                                            <Label x:Name="lblQuantity" 
                                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                                   FontSize="15"
                                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                                   HeightRequest="20"
                                                                   />



                                        </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want the label to be more apart from the buttons and I don't know why but the buttons keep changing their size when clicked

Comment: I saw you have resolved your problem,right? Congrats.  Could you please mark the useful answer as marked ?Thanks in advance. :)